# How do I use user input in Task Scheduler program?

Tags: c++, windows-task-scheduler

I'm creating a program that takes input on the tasks name, the file that it executes, and when. I found sample code from Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384042%28v=vs.85%29 and I'm using it.

I don't know how to use user input when when naming the task:

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  Create a name for the task.
LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L"Weekly Trigger Task";
```

I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  Create a name for the task.
LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L<<taskname;
```

Does anyone know? Thanks,
-Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean from a console application then you can use the [gets()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2029ea5f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function (or its Visual Studio Unicode equivalent _getws()).

```
WSTR wszTaskName[256];
_getws(wszTaskName);
```